# returning HSSFSheet from a class method

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a servlet which is creating an Excel workbook.

I have the first sheet of the workbook working as desired and would like to reuse that code, as some subsequent sheets will have the same code with differing data and formatting.

I believe this puts me in a position to put this code into its own method, rather than duplicate it several times in a doPost().  My challenge is how do I create a sheet and pass it without having to put it in a workbook and pass the workbook, as well?

Or do I need to worry about that?  Should I create a dummy workbook, create the sheet in the workbook and the return the sheet from the method, anyway?

Or am I stuck having to put all of this in my doPost, repeatedly?

Answer (score 1):

Normally I avoid coding functions with side effects (makes changes to input objects) but in this case this may be what you need.

something like (psudocode):

```
public Workbook addSheet(WorkBook addSheetToMe, Object otherParams){

   Sheet theSheetToAdd = new Sheet();

   // Fill Sheet with Stuff

   addSheetToMe.addSheet(theSheetToAdd);

   return addSheetToMe;
}
```

Comment: True, I considered passing the workbook but I wasn't sure what side effects would be from passing it back and forth to multiple methods, multiple times.  I will try this and see if it works.